# Biopython globalcc returns empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

I am using Biopython's globalcc function to align a standardized version of a word and a dialectal version. Unfortunately, sometimes the alignment fails for no obvious reasons and an empty list is returned.

```
align.globalcc(Word,Dialectal,matchfunc,gapfunctionA,gapfunctionB,gap_char=['-'])
```

Using "lyödään","lywwään" as the word pair fails even though the program works as expected for many close variants (I tested it for "lyödään","lywään" for example and it returned the expected alignment).

Edit : Ok so it seems the problem is with the matching function. By using a less severe penalty for aligning some characters, globalcc returns at least one alignment. I'm still puzzled by the behavior however since I was under the impression that globalcc was sorting through possible alignments i.e the best alignment should be returned under all circumstances even if its score is abysmally low.